# Subquery returns multiple rows error

Tags: sql, oracle

In Oracle I have a table like this with 3 columns:

### Table_A

```
issue_no | source_no | status 
-------------------------------
1           A
2           A
3           B
```

`issue_no` is unique, but there are no `status` values.

I have another table, B, where I have the `status` for each `source` (not `issue_no`):

### Table_B

```
source_no  | status
-------------------
A            Complete
B            Progress
```

I would like to update the `status` column in Table_A with the `status` from Table_B. Seemed easy enough, but when I execute:

```
update Table_A a
  set status  = (select status
                   from Table_B b
                   where a.source_no = b.source_no )
  where exists (select *
                  from Table_B b
                  where a.source_no = b.souce_no)
```

I get an error that the subquery does return multiple rows and cannot update. How can I get past this error? Using `distinct` does not help I get the same error.

Comment: Why do you want to denormalize? What is intent of the `where` clause in the `update` statement (i.e. what are you missing if you chopped that off)?

Comment: Are you sure this is exactly the setup? You shouldn't get any errors. I suspect in your actual example (not what you posted here) you may have non-unique values in `source_no` in `Table_B`.

Comment: some possible workarounds are 1) use a MIN() or MAX() aggregate in the SELECT list of the subuery, for example **`= (select MAX(status) from ...`** (to guarantee no more than one row is returned by the subquery),  or 2) include a predicate on ROWNUM  ... **`.. where a.source_no = b.source_no AND ROWNUM < 2)`**, again, to guarantee no more than one row is returned.  But I'm not liking either of those workarounds. It seems like those shouldn't be necessary.  We're wondering why `source_no` isn't unique in `Table_B` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
update table_A
   set status = b.status
from table_A a
     inner join table_B b on a.source_no = b.source_no
```

This is standard construction.

### Update with full sample:

```
create table #table_a(issue_no int, source_no char, status varchar(10))
insert #table_a(issue_no,source_no) values (1,'A'),(2,'A'),(3,'B')
create table #table_b(source_no char,status varchar(10))
insert #table_b values ('A','Complete'),('B','Progress')
select * from #table_a
select * from #table_b

update #table_A
   set status = b.status
from #table_A a
     inner join #table_B b on a.source_no = b.source_no
select * from #table_a
```

last select:

```
issue_no    source_no   status
1   A   Complete
2   A   Complete
3   B   Progress
```

What line doesn't follow ANSI 92 or work differently in Oracle?

Comment: Standard?? This won't even compile - incorrect syntax. I can't even guess what you meant.

Comment: the query is created in MS SQL server. Probably Oracle use different version of ANSI 92.

Comment: The question is tagged Oracle. What is the use/help of offering a SQL Server solution? Besides, I doubt that what you wrote will work in any DB, did you test it in SQL Server? Your join will produce two columns named `status`. There is no `b.status` column in the join.